# Maps.uniqueIndex() for Multimap?

Tags: java, guava

We can use `Maps.uniqueIndex()` to create a `Map` out of any `Iterable` which is very handy. But I need to create a `Multimap` and I'm having `Iterable`, is there any nice way to create a `Multimap` from `Iterable` just like - `Maps.uniqueIndex()`

If it doesn't have any utility method then would like to see other guava approach to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you want [`Multimaps.index`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).